# meaning of phrase

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a story in English: it's not my native language. I don't understand what does phrase below mean?

> Chris takes in the sloe-eyed tilt of his head, the mussed hair that must have come from the padded headgear.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of this sentence is `takes in`.

To *take in* means to observe and then consider its significance.

This means that Chris observes these characteristics (the sloe-eyed tilt of his head and the mussed hair) of the other character and judges something about the character based off them.